# How to terminate parsing on invalid values?

Tags: python-3.x, antlr4

I'm parsing CSV like format and date fields allow different formats (and typos) thus I have simple lexer and parser grammar:

```
// Parser
<snip>
contract_date: na | TEXT;
na: ;

// Lexer
<snip>
TEXT: ~[;\n\r]+;
```

Then date validation is performed in `ParserListener`:

```
class CSVExport(ParserListener):
    def __init__(self, handle):
    ...

    def enterContract_date(self, ctx):
        self.record['contract_date'] = self.normalise_date(ctx.getText())

    def normalise_date(self, text):
        if not text.strip():
            return ''

        for fmt in ('%d/%m/%Y', '00%y%m%d', '02%y%m%d', '%Y%m%d', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'):
            try:
                return datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(text, fmt), '%Y-%m-%d')
            except ValueError:
                pass

        print('Oh no...')
        raise ParseCancellationException('no valid date format found ({})'.format(text))
```

I would like to get exceptions to be handled by parser it self thus get nice error message from antler instead of stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Context object `ctx` has `start.line` and `start.column` attributes.

After small refactoring, context is passed to date parsing function which can throw `Exception` with correct line and column numbers:

```
class CSVExport(ParserListener):
    def __init__(self, handle):
    ...

    def enterContract_date(self, ctx):
        self.record['contract_date'] = self.normalise_date(ctx)

    def normalise_date(self, ctx):
        text = ctx.getText()
        if not text.strip():
            return ''

        for fmt in ('%d/%m/%Y', '00%y%m%d', '02%y%m%d', '%Y%m%d', '%Y%m%d %H:%M'):
            try:
                return datetime.strftime(datetime.strptime(text, fmt), '%Y-%m-%d')
            except ValueError:
                pass

        raise Exception('Invalid date "{}" at ({}, {})'.format(text, ctx.start.line, ctx.start.column))
```